# Node.js in aws callback variable

Tags: node.js, callback, aws-lambda

Hi im trying to use callback for variable external use outside the function but something is wrong, i think my callback is not so correct as i think:

```
function latitude(callback){
  var mylat;
  const https = require('https');
     https.get('https://url_of_my_json', (resp) => {
     let data = '';


  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
     resp.on('end', () => {
     mylat = JSON.parse(data).results[0].geometry.location.lat;
     callback(mylat);

     });


  }).on("error", (err) => {
   console.log("Error: " + err.message);
 });

}

var mylat = latitude(); // variable i want to use for the rest of code
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the callback is incorrect.

here is the example, for better understanding of callback Try this example as simple as you can read, just copy save newfile.js do node newfile to run the application.

```
function myNew(next){
    console.log("Im the one who initates callback");
    next("nope", "success");
}


myNew(function(err, res){
    console.log("I got back from callback",err, res);
});
```

happy coding :)